# Efficiently submit infinite number of tasks to a Java ThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I would like to know what is the best Design Pattern for this:
I have infinite tasks I can handle, each task is of various size (problem size). For this, I have created a ThreadPool (2 core pool, 4 max pool) with a PriorityBlockingQueue.

Whenever I execute the task, it's being added to the pool with a priority. The problem arises when I have 2 tasks that can take a while (say, 10 min for example) and they fill the core pool. So whenever I try to submit a new task, I can check whenever they are still at work using **getTaskCount** and **getCorePoolSize** and then add the new task to the current queue instead. Now, what happens when the 2 tasks take really long time (way more than 5, 10, 20 mins) How do I being to accept new tasks that can take 1sec, 3 sec... etc to complete? Do I need to put a timeout on each runnable I create for my task in order to make sure it dies?

hope someone can give some extra hand.
thanks!

Comment: Is it normal for those long running tasks to take that much time? If not then a timeout might help, if it is normal then you might want to consider a pool for long running tasks or, if possible, splitting those tasks or make them support suspend/resume and work on them only when there's free capacity.

Comment: Another thing you might want to consider is task stealing, i.e. if you have worker threads that don't have anything to do they could check another thread's queue (or a common queue) and "steal" a task from there. This way you'd not have to think about which thread to associate the tasks with - just provide a common queue (or several) that's sorted by priority.

Comment: @Thomas sometimes I am getting a problem-task that my algorithm is unable to resolve in a reasonable time and might get stuck finding solution - it's a bug in itself, but either way, this thread edge case is something I would like to understand as a design pattern rather than an algorithm problem. so it happens I receive 2 running tasks which are "unsolvable" and the core pool is filled, and when i send another easy to solve the task, i just add it to the queue, but the pool will probably never reach it. so I wonder if the only solution is a kill-timer in each task's runnable run method.

Comment: Well, in that case it seems as if you don't know whether a task could get stuck or not. Thus a kill-timer would probably the most common way to solve that. Another thing you could try, as I tried to hint at already, would be to use some suspend/resume mechanism, i.e. the longer a task takes to finish the lower its priority gets and if a new task with a high enough priority comes in then the long running task gets suspended and is resumed when resources (threads) are available. If it's really stuck though, you'd eventually have to kill it.

Comment: Note: you can timeout a task but this doesn't force it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a construct such as this?

```
class Scratch {

    public static ExecutorService   pool    = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    public static AtomicInteger     runnableCount = new AtomicInteger();

    // Returns the next task that needs to run - insert your logic here
    // This method will be called whenever the previous Runnable is done
    public static Runnable getNextRunnable() {
        return () -> {
            System.out.println("Runnable " + runnableCount.incrementAndGet() + " Doing work");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10); // Sleep to prevent runaway endless loop
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        };
    }

    // Submits the next task to the pool, adds callback to add next task
    public static void submitNextRunnable(Void ignored) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(getNextRunnable(), pool);
        future.thenAccept(Scratch::submitNextRunnable);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        submitNextRunnable(null);
    }
}
```

The above code starts by creating an `Executor` and submitting a single `Runnable`. And whenever a `Runnable` is submitted, we give it a callback function that will submit the next Runnable when the previous one is done. It's recursive.

The output of that code is an endless stream of `Runnables` printing their execution:

```
Runnable 1 Doing work
Runnable 2 Doing work
Runnable 3 Doing work
Runnable 4 Doing work
Runnable 5 Doing work
Runnable 6 Doing work
Runnable 7 Doing work
Runnable 8 Doing work
Runnable 9 Doing work
Runnable 10 Doing work
Runnable 11 Doing work
Runnable 12 Doing work
Runnable 13 Doing work
Runnable 14 Doing work
```

This way you don't need timeous or polling the executor's taks count. You simply get a callback every time the previous `Runnable` is complete.
If you want to submit several tasks at once, just call `submitNextRunnable(null);` multiple times.